# How to access single-storey a from FiraSans

Tags: fonts

I need a sans serif font with visually differnt 'I' and 'l' and a single-storey 'a'.
The closest i found was [FiraSans Regular](http://tug.org/FontCatalogue/firasansregular/) but it lacks the single-storey 'a'. However, there is a comment in the `/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/fira/Fira_4_2_Version_Log.pdf` which says:

> _ Single-storey alternates for a and g accessible via .ss04 (#127)

I take this as a hint, that a single-storey 'a' is available, but how am i supposed to activate this? For example in this document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
This is a Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is available with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lualatex or xelatex you can use the font feature like this (tested with texlive 2020, go for a coffee when trying the first time with lualatex, the package consists of many fonts and lualatex has to create lots of lua file during the first compilation):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\sffamily]{RawFeature={+ss04}}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\begin{document}
This is a Test.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With pdflatex it is theoretically possible to use the glyph, it is there. If is has the same width as the normal a, you could exchange it with a local encoding file.